# Getting Quartz to scale the screen resolution for Retina display

Tags: osx-yosemite, macbook-pro-retina, vdi, xquartz

I am using a VDI client (Exceed On Demand) that uses Quartz (X11) to display on my Retina display.  When setting the display resolution to default, the X11 window doesn't fit.  When setting it for "More Space" the application shows the entire 1280x1024 display, but all of the other applications are too small.

Is it possible to get Quartz to scale itself to fit in the display on a pixel to pixel basis?  This is with being able to have the scaling for the other apps to be set to default.

Answer (score 0):

Until recently, I used EoD on Mac OS. During that time I found XQuartz to be extremely painful and buggy. Your question is one of the issues I had with XQuartz. I recently switched to FastX. As far as I'm concerned it is better for Mac OS in all ways. I know it doesn't answer your question, but give it a try and you won't miss EoD. Dynamic resizing (not scaling), no graphics degradation, sessions persist. Can be installed on VM and run as non-root - don't need IT support. Only requires SSH access on port 22. Make sure to use the desktop client and not the web client. It's awesome!